# Model not working in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Controller Name : **UserController.php**

```
public function getIndex()
{
     $users = DB::table('users')->get(); //Working
     $users = User::all(); //Not Working
}
```

Model Name : **User.php**

```
class User extends Eloquent {}
```

What is the problem with ORM eloquent ??
I m using Laravel 4.2.6

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ? Any exception, error message ?

Comment: please define "not working". we dont know what you mean by that.

Comment: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'User' not found

Comment: you have this file in app/models ?

Comment: Of course I have placed in that directory . 
I got it solved anyway. The problem was I only declared the class like this , "clas User extends Eloquent{}" . Instead of that I did what delmadord suggested . It worked but I'm still confused why this single line is not enough in User model . WHy I have to add this extra code "class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface " just to do my "User:all()" query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fresh laravel 4.2 User model looks like this

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

I believe it should like like this to get it to work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these traits and interfaces are only required for user-specific operations such as password reminders, authentication, etc but not for a basic `User::all()`.

Comment: The User model was like this . It was having the same problem back then.

Comment: Angish Tangbe: given the exception you provided in the comments in your question, did you try `composer dump-autoload` command?

Comment: I followed the document in laravel.com . It only told me to write class User extends Eloquent {} in model . I reinstalled laravel and it worked . Does "class User extends Eloquent {} " declaration is not enough ?

Comment: No it is not. You can see in fresh Laravel installation that there are other lines of code that are needed for a full documented functionality.

Comment: delmadord : Yes I tried composer dump-autoload back then but the result was the same. Downloading Fresh copy worked for me . Thanks for your help .

Comment: delmadord : Yes the User model has got the same code as you suggested . But in laravel documentation it only says that one line declaration is enough !!

Comment: I will take a look at the documentation correctness. Thanks for pointing out. May I ask where did you find that information?